miele calima vacuum cleaner made for US but want to use in france
I have a Miele 300- 1200 W vacuum , model called calima which has a US plug. I have a  voltage transformer step up and step down made by LVUAN. It says VTEU 500VA on the front where the US plug goes in. On the back it says Input:230VAC/230VAC, Output 110VAC/230VAC. Can I use them together effectively ?

Just sell it and buy one made for EU.
Much safer, as the vacuum on max is about double that transformer that you have.
This has been asked before for many items and the answer is always the same.

This is not a good idea for several reasons:
Frequency
A vacuum cleaner generally has a large motor designed for a particular voltage range (e.g., 110V - 125V or 200V - 250V) and frequency. While a transformer can relatively cheaply/easily convert voltage, much more complicated equipment is required to convert frequency. The US frequency, and therefore the design frequency for products sold in the US, is 60 Hz. The European frequency is 50 Hz. That is close enough that it might work. But also different enough that it could lead to any combination of: poor performance, overheating, motor self-destruct (after a time, not immediately) or FIRE. Don't try it.
Capacity
For situations where a transformer is appropriate, you have to make sure that the transformer is large enough to handle the load. Your vacuum cleaner is rated at 1200 W. Your transformer is rated at 500 VA, and VA is essentially equal to W in this context (close enough). If you run a transformer at significantly higher than its rated capacity then, depending on the quality of the transformer (dubious here), you will end up with one or more of:

Transformer shuts down - safe but not terribly useful
Transformer overheats and then shuts down - safe but only useful for a little while
Transformer overheats and does not shut down - which means a good chance of a fire destroying more than just the transformer

Quality/Certification
This device is almost certainly not properly certified, and almost as certainly, not properly designed, for use as advertised in most countries. In the US, the relevant certification is generally UL or ETL. It varies in other locations. For a lot of products that really doesn't matter. But for things connecting to your AC electric power supply, particularly when designed to use a lot of power (this isn't a little 5W USB adapter, and even those have had problems with poor design), there are many risks involved. UL, ETL and similar organizations have design guidelines and testing processes to make sure that products are properly designed for their intended use and safe so that even if they fail nobody gets hurt.
In addition to fire, other possible problems include:

Miswiring/poor design leading to exposed parts of the device carrying dangerous voltage/current that could injure or even kill someone.
Poor design leading to early failure. Many products of this type have warranties but the companies know that even if they have to honor warranty claims to stay on Amazon, a high percentage of failures will just be tossed rather than returned because the buyer will decide that it is not worth the effort to bother returning it. This is particularly the case for travel products: Buy this in the US from Amazon, take it with you on a trip to Europe, then it fails early and it doesn't make sense to bring it all the way back to the US just to return it.
Incorrect or inconsistent results - e.g., wrong output voltage or voltage varying significantly as the load changes (vacuum on low setting vs. high setting).

